# Getting encoding straight in Access 2007

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ms-access-2007

I have an UTF-8 encoded file that I want to read data from and put in a table.

To do this correctly, I would need to know the following:

1. What is the default encoding in Access 2007, if you just create a database and create a table and create some fields without changing any default settings?
2. Can something in a database be encoded with a different encoding than the default one? I.e. can this be set, like it can for all other databases?
3. If so, on what "level"? I.e. for the whole database, a whole table, or individual fields?

Comment: You can either read the manual or code up some simple examples to see if what you ask is possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I RTFM'd.

1. UTF-8.
2. No (from googling). You can get your text converted to UTF-8 at import by setting Connection Charset for the "source" Datasource.
3. See 2.